# What does this E symbol mean?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, notation, gan

What does this E symbol mean?

[image]

It is from the [GAN paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661).

Comment: Uppercase "E" is one of the very few symbols in statistics that almost always have the same meaning: [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

Comment: @tim thanks, maybe leave that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: I love that we googled this exact thing, GAN paper and everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In mathematics and statistics many symbols are used to denote different things, e.g. [$\pi$ does not always have to be the $3.14.15...$ constant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296677/difference-between-px-vs-pix-in-literature/296681#296681). However the uppercase "E" (written in many forms, e.g. $\mathbb{E}, E, \mathrm{E}$) is almost always used in statistics to denote the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). In the case of your equation

$$
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_\text{data}(x)}\left( \log D(x) \right)
$$

means: the expected value of $\log D(x)$ given $x$ [distributed as](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183046/what-exactly-does-dot-sim-notation-mean/183050#183050) $p_\text{data}(x)$.